# Units of cuda registers

Tags: cuda, size, units-of-measurement

Can anyone tell me what the units of NVIDIA cuda registers are? When I have 8192 registers per block, it means is in bytes or bits?

Answer (score 14, accepted):

Each of the registers is a 32-bit register, i.e. there are 4 bytes per register.

Comment: Is this still valid in newer compute capabilities?

Comment: @AnixPasBesoin Yes.